# Liberar subdiretorio através do .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, servidor

Como faço para liberar um sub diretório específico (e todos os seus arquivos) via .htaccess?

Como utilizo "url amigável" e através do `.htaccess` faço bloqueio de tudo aquilo que não convém, gostaria de saber como "liberar" o acesso à uma pasta em específico e todos os arquivos nela.

**OBS:**
o comando `<Directory /path/to/dir/protected/unprotected> Satisfy An </Directory>` não resolveu o meu problema, pois o mesmo deve ser colocado no `httpd.conf` e não tenho acesso ao mesmo. Na pergunta citada como "respondida" o autor provavelmente tem este acesso, e sendo desta forma, a minha dúvida não está respondida ainda. Farei um novo teste.

**Resultado do teste:**
Em testes locais no arquivo `httpd.conf` resposta da pergunta sinalizada como respondida funciona perfeitamente, mas se o mesmo ser colocado em um `.htaccess` é retornado o erro

> Internal Server Error

Para o meu problema não tenho acesso ao arquivo `httpd.conf` e o mesmo deve ser realizado no arquivo `.htaccess`. Por isso a dúvida de como liberar um diretório específico via `.htaccess`.

Comment: qual versão do apache você esta usando? 2.2 ou 2.4? poderia adicionar seu .htaccess no conteúdo da pergunta para melhor entendimento?

Comment: No caso gostaria apenas tornar uma determinada pasta para acesso "público" junto com todo o seu conteúdo interno.

Comment: acho que minha resposta satisfaz seu problema... =)

Answer (score 2):

Imaginando a seguinte estrutura:

```
public_html/
├── pasta_x/
├── pasta_y/
└── pasta_z/
```

Vamos usar como exemplo que você queira que a pasta `pasta_y` seja acessada publicamente, então o seguinte código será adicionado ao seu .htaccess:
**EDITADO:** Caso a opção `Options +Indexes` esteja ativada no seu virtualHost.

```
<Directory “caminho/absoluto/pasta_y/”>
    #para Apache 2.2
    Order Allow, Deny
    Allow From All

    #para Apache 2.4
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Caso o código acima não funcione, você pode criar um arquivo .htaccess dentro do diretório `pasta_y`com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
#para Apache 2.2
Order Allow, Deny
Allow From All

#para Apache 2.4
Require all granted
```