# Como liberar uma pasta específica através do uso de htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, permissões

Preciso liberar dentro de **lib** só a pasta **barcode**. O resto é inacessível. Como posso fazer isso? O que tenho atualmente é:

Order deny, allow
Deny from all

Answer (score -1):

Tenta criar um arquivo de configuracao liberando exclusivamente esta pasta Lib.

Veja um exemplo com os seguintes soluções já postadas:

[Como liberar um sub-diretório protegido com .htaccess?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1710/como-liberar-um-sub-diret%C3%B3rio-protegido-com-htaccess)

[Liberar subdiretorio através do .htaccess](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65357/liberar-subdiretorio-atrav%C3%A9s-do-htaccess)